# How to ignore the warning: Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum?

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, sql-server-2012

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.4 and SQL Server driver 11.2.1.jre8 on Java 8 to connect to SQL Server 2012 database which uses TLSv1
and the project runs on Tomcat 9.

JDBC driver dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

My connection URL is as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://myhostname;databaseName=mydb;encrypt=false;
```

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16) setting `encrypt=false` will disable TLS encryption for all the data sent between the client and the server.

But I keep getting this warning:

> [WARN] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum.
> [WARN] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: null

I cannot make changes on the database server right now to update it to use TLSv1.2, so is there any database connecting property I need to add or some Spring configuration to avoid this error ?

### Update

I didn't get this error when I was using **mssql-jdbc-8.2.1.jre8.jar**, so is there any solution other than downgrading the JDBC driver ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you just have to live with the warning, and possibly hide it.  As I say in other comments, the existence can be seen as a feature.  It's just stating what the reality is, which you've already explained why can't be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell for sure, but since you're using Spring, I assume that the warning you show is being emitted by the standard Spring logging system.  If that's the case, and if that message has a level of WARN, then you can hide that warning by setting the logging level for the indicated package to ERROR in your application.properties file, like this:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR
```

Of course, this is going to hide ALL warnings for that package.  If that's not what you want, then I don't think there's anything you can do.  I've often wanted something more granular myself...some way to eliminate particular warnings with a regular expression or something.  I've never found such a feature in any of the standard logging systems.

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you think that there's no connection property needed to avoid this warning ?

Comment: Maybe there is such a property.  I was just now realizing that maybe I misunderstood your question.  I thought you'd already decided that you couldn't get the code to not log the message, and you only wanted to have it not print to your screen. Obviously, finding a way to have the warning not occur at all would be better.  I don't know of a way to do that, but I can sympathize.  I've been in the same boat with TLS settings myself.

Comment: Ha ha!  I'm glad you clarified your situation by commenting on the other answer.  If the server can only use the older version of the protocol, then the code is doing the best thing it can do, which is to warn you that it must use the earlier version.  If you want to hide the warning or not is up to you. If you do want to hide it, try what I  suggest.

Comment: I added another update to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in VM options in IDEA or pass it in console while trying to start program.

`-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2`

[image]

Comment: Not a solution because this will enforce TLSv1.2 and the database server is tls v1

Comment: Ah.  That's the key bit of information @MahmoudSaleh.   If you can't cause the server to use v1.2, then there's nothing you can do to change the actual behavior.  The server can't do what it can't do.  And the warning is then appropriate, since it's good that you know that your connection is being downgraded to an earlier version of the protocol.  You might update your question to make it clear that SQL Server can ONLY use v1.

Comment: When Using earlier version of the jdbc driver I didn't get this behavior that's why I am guessing there might be a connection property to add to avoid this error

Comment: It makes good sense that updating your driver would cause this new warning.  The whole point of the warning is to warn you that there is now a better option.  Maybe version 1.2 wasn't out when the older version of the driver came out, or maybe it was available but wasn't yet in common use.  Or maybe the developer just decided last month that a warning should be emitted.  In any case, the warning can be seen as a feature rather than a bug.  So you need to just deal with it regardless of why it has just started to appear (or not...you can just ignore it).